# How to edit DCOM CONFIG component programmatically using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Below configuration settings need to be added/done programmatically over “Component Services>>Computers>>My Computer>>DCOM Config>>CDTUHandler”.

Need to edit security for provide Launch and Activation permission to any user over 
CDTUHandler component using Asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F0PP.jpg)

Comment: That's a strange thing to want... you should be able to configure your server once  with whatever is convenient and not try to do it from ASP.Net code...

Comment: My Project build is installed in client machine. Its a long process if we configure this required DCOM setting manually on each client machine. My requirement is, this permission should be done by C# program

We want to give DCOM setting only on one particular component and this component is already delivered by project using programming.

Have any suggestion/way for doing this task. ...